# Auto Slide - revolunet's angular-carousel

Tags: angularjs, carousel

So I've seen the angular carousel developed by Revolunet and the offer features like **rn-carousel-auto-slide**. The problem is where should I inject this feature into my code? I have tried injecting it into several different tags but cant seem to get it work.. Hope some one would lend me a hand in solving this... Below is my code on implementation...

```
    <div class="exploreCarousel">
    <div ng-controller="CarouselCtrl"
        ng-init="init(<?php echo $topic_id?>)" id="slides_control">
        <ul rn-carousel class="image" rn-carousel-indicator>
          <li ng-repeat="image in slides">
            <div><img ng-src="<?php echo UrlMgmt::getExploreImageUrl()?>{{image.image}}" class="layer" rn-carousel-auto-slide/></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this would be the link to Revolunet's repository in case I did not make it clear to you guys.

https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that rn-carousel-auto-slide has a bug, I just tried to make it work and browsed through it's code.
it uses element.children() to find out how many slides there are, but does this only once at initiation time - it will work for staticly inserted slides hard coded into the HTML - you should add it to the UL tag. but because you want to use it together with ng-repeat, it needs to be altered to check the element's children's length after ng-repeat has finished or check it in every iteration of the increment function.
I will fix it and make a pull request soon.
meanwhile add this:   (you must use the src version of the module and directives rather than the minified, and you should make this change after copying rn-carousel-auto-slide.js to somewhere outside bower_components (assuming you use bower etc.....)

```
$timeout(function () {
      slidesCount = element.children().length;
}, 100); // can probably be shorter but this is safe.
```

Comment: Dear Nadav SInai, I've follow your method and it works flawlessly at the moment... Thank you so much for helping me in understanding how the functions work. Please do inform me once you've made the pull request available... Thank you so much mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to touch to the files actually, here is how to do it:

set `rn-carousel-index="cpos"`
and in your controller:

```
var position = false,
  interval = 5000,
  slides = [
  {
    image: './images/carousel/image-1.jpg',
    title: 'this is the title',
    link: '//beta.dungeondefenders.com',
    text: 'this is the description, can be long, can be long, can be long, can be long, can be long, can be long'
  },
  {
    image: './images/carousel/image-2.jpg',
    title: 'this is the title',
    link: '//beta.dungeondefenders.com',
    text: 'this is the description, can be long, can be long, can be long, can be long, can be long, can be long'
  }];


$interval(function () {
  var newPos = 0;
  if(position) {
    newPos = $scope.cpos +1;
    if(newPos > slides.length -1) {
      newPos = 0;
    }
  } else {
    position = true;
  }

  logger.info(position,newPos,slides.length-1);
  $scope.cpos = newPos;
}, interval);

$scope.cpos = position;
$scope.slides = slides;
```

that is still a workaround though.

Comment: You should make a pull request with a fix! :)